# How to pull the shooter rod on a pinball game using a servo of some kind

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I want to use a computer to initiate a game on a physical pinball game. (This is to see if I can get the computer to learn to play pinball using machine vision and deep Q networks.) I want to pull the shooter rod out that is used to send the ball into play. You pull back on the shooter rod and release it to send the ball up to the top of the play field. I need to create a hardware solution that can grip and release this so that it strikes the ball under computer control. You can see what it looks like in the image. I can use the computer to run a servo or electromagnet to initiate it somehow but I'm not sure what configuration would be easiest/best to implement. Although it would be nice, its not really important to control how far the shooter rod is pulled.

It seems to me I need a thing that can pull it back and then maybe a solenoid to release the grip suddenly. What kind of hardware solution do you think would work?

[image: pinball image]

Comment: Whatcha gonna do with all the SS games that have a button-launcher?

Comment: I have seen pinball games that had an auto-shooter mechanism - for certain events in the game it would fire the next ball automatically. These appear to be driven by a coil, they don't affect operation of the manual rod/spring. Would that do?  (I think Carl has just mentioned a similar idea in his comment by the way.)

Comment: Yeah some of them have an auto shooter but I need to use this one. The reason is that I am building a system where the computer learns to play the game using reinforcement learning. I need the score to be constantly available and these older games have a seven segment display and its fairly easy to get the score information. The games I have available that have a button launcher use dot matrix graphics displays which show a bunch of animations and don't always show the score.

Answer (score 2):

[image: Pinball shooter]

Not the most elegant solution, or probably the best, but simple(ish):

I'd attach a lever to the puller to extend it out beyond the side (or just create space between the handle and the machine, then use a motor to spin a second lever with a bearing on it that pulls the lever back. as it spins through 90 degrees it'll release so no need for a solenoid.

As long as there's space, you should be able to adjust the length of the motor lever to lengthen or shorten the travel, and again if you leave space the motor can just spin right around to catch the lever next time (more space than there is in my sketch!).

Any of that make sense?

Comment: Not gonna work.  You'd need all sorts of moving platforms to get the release motor and extractor arm to track the handle's position.

Comment: To me this seems like it would work. I'm not sure I understand the problem with it.

Comment: @Robotbugs I think the problem Carl's seeing is a design like this might interfere with people also playing the machine. But that may not be a problem in your application.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback all, but not sure i follow carls comment, the handle is presumably spring return so it'll return to the same position? Once the bearing has rolled off the edge of the handle and released the ball the motor will just rotate through the remaining 270ish degrees to catch the lever again... maybe my notebook sketch isn't up to scratch...

Answer (score 1):

Well, since IAAP (physicist) **and** IAAPF (pinball fanatic), I guess I'll chime in.  There's really no substitute for a locking pawl here.  You probably should replace the human-rated handle on the shooter shaft with something more like a right circular cylinder.  The pawl & solenoid combo are spring-loaded, so driving the entire mechanism forward allows the pawl to engage the afore-mentioned cylinder. Use a motor or whatever to pull the shaft back as far as desired, then fire the solenoid to release the pawl.

Lame attempt at diagram follows....[image: plunger operator]

Comment: Very nice diagram really! Thanks for the work you put in to draw that!

Comment: Seems like the thing that pulls the shooter back would have to be attached to the solenoid not the shooter as it would have to disengage with the shooter. I did think of maybe a linear actuator with a claw on the end.

Comment: @Robotbugs That's correct:  My design assumes a platform which holds the solenoid and claw, and moves forward and backwards.